# Hugo: Turn a map into an array of alternating keys and values

Tags: hugo

The `dict` function turns arguments into a map:

```
{{ $m := dict "a" "b" "c" "d" }}
```

How do I do the reverse? I need an array of `"a" "b" "c" "d"` given that map.

I need that to pass to the `querify` function, which unfortunately does not accept a map.

Answer (score 0):

A `dict` defines a key/value pair object

```
{{ $m := dict "key1" "value1" "key2" "value2" }}
```

To get an array, you need to use `slice`

```
{{ $m := slice "a" "b" "c" "d" }}
```

There is not really a conversion from a `dict` to an `array`, because the object structure is not the same.